# Outer autorelease pool

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I don't understand why we need the outer autorelease pool (around `UIApplicationMain` and inside `NSApplicationMain`). Won't all the allocated memory be freed when the process terminates anyways?

For example, what if I just did this:

```
@import Foundation;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < NSUIntegerMax; i++) {
        NSArray *anArray = [NSArray array];
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a framework invariant. The framework depends on the existence of an autorelease pool. If there is no autorelease pool, your program will spam errors to the log. The program will still probably run and the memory will still be freed at exit, but the framework still wants there to be a pool in place for it to call to.

Answer (score -1):

You're correct, all memory will get released when the process exits. But the point of the autorelease pool is so memory gets released *before* then. (In your example, you are "abandoning" memory -- allocating and then forgetting about the allocations.) Otherwise, you're just leaking memory until the system can't allocate any more for the process, in which case the process gets killed.

Comment: NSApplicationMain() and UIApplicationMain() never return, so the autorelease pool around them is in fact never released.